# Supply default metadata to a drop off library upload form

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, metadata, records-management, records-center

I have created a custom page where I supply a search query string (k=Param:Value) that only have a results webpart (no search form). It is intended to be called from our CRM (Dynamics) in the form `http://sp2013-portal/show_documents.aspx?k=ClientId:123` so we can display all the documents associated with this client. All this is working fine.

I then added a button on my page to upload the document into the drop off library using the builtin upload.aspx form. All this is working fine.

What I would like to do is pass my original parameter ClientId:123 to the drop off library so it can automatically feed the ClientId metadata. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I sort of achieved what I wanted. I created a custom editform.aspx that uses some javascript to fetch the clientId from the window.parent.location and puts it in the clientid field. This is not an ideal solution, but that works for now.